# simple javascript loop

Tags: javascript, loops, input, extendscript

this is extendscript for illustrator, its basically javascript though. I want the second pop up to only show once, I tried to tell it if the variable already exists to not do it, but if it doesn't to ask for input. any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
#target illustrator
if ( app.documents.length > 0 ) {
    var replaceThis = prompt('What font do you want to replace?','')
    for ( i = 0; i< app.activeDocument.textFrames.length; i++) { //loop through the layers
        var textArtRange = app.activeDocument.textFrames[i].textRange;
        var fontSize = textArtRange.characterAttributes.size;
        //var replaceThis = "10";
        //alert("replace this:" + replaceThis);
       // alert("current font size" + fontSize);
        if (fontSize == replaceThis) {
             Replacefont();
         }
        function Replacefont () {
                //var newSize = "90";
                if (!newSize) {
                    var newSize = prompt('Replace '+ replaceThis +'pt with:','')
                }
                textArtRange.characterAttributes.size = newSize;
                alert("yay");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newSize` is only available inside `ReplaceFont`, and is discarded each time the function ends. You'd need to make it persistent like this (there is no real reason for making a separate function). Also don't forget `var` for the `for` loop.

```
#target illustrator
if ( app.documents.length > 0 ) {
    var replaceThis = prompt('What font do you want to replace?','');
    var newSize = prompt('Replace '+ replaceThis +'pt with:','');

    for ( var i = 0; i < app.activeDocument.textFrames.length; i++) {
        var textArtRange = app.activeDocument.textFrames[i].textRange;
        var fontSize = textArtRange.characterAttributes.size;

        if (fontSize == replaceThis) {
            textArtRange.characterAttributes.size = newSize;
            alert("yay");
        }
    }
}
```